# Best practice for testing return value of indexOf

Tags: java, javascript

What do you normally write when you're testing for the return value of indexOf?

```
if str.indexOf("a") < 0
```

vs

```
if str.indexOf("a") == -1
```

Would one method be preferred over the other?

I'm actually posing this question for any function in any language that returns -1 on error.

I normally prefer the < 0 approach, because if the function is extended to return -2 on some other case, the code would still work.

However, I notice that the == -1 approach is more commonly used. Is there a reason why?

Comment: In the case of Java, indexOf clearly specifies that it will return -1 if no match is found in your string. Therefore, changing that would be a break in the API and we can therefore count on the fact that it will return -1. But I prefer too use the `<0` over the `==-1`

Comment: `if (!~str.indexOf("a"))` is a bit less verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I try to implement the general principle that tests for "error conditions" should be as wide as possible.  Hence I would use `< 0` rather than `== -1`.

This is a principle I was taught during classes in formal methods during my CS degree.

On a simple `if` it doesn't matter too much, but on loops it's important to detect any "out of range" condition to ensure that the loop is terminated, and not to assume that the loop termination value will be hit exactly.

Take for example this:

```
i = 0;
while (i < 10) {
    ++i;
    // something else increments i
}
```

v.s.

```
i = 0;
while (i != 10) {
    ++i;
    // something else increments i
}
```

The latter case could fail - the former case won't.

Comment: but in this case Java API is specifically telling us that -1 will be returned.

Comment: it is, but it's implicit that an integer value of 0 or higher will be returned on success, so the opposite (i.e. `< 0`) is a perfectly valid counter test.

Comment: If -2 is returned, it doesn't mean "not found". It is undefined.. wouldn't you rather expect the code to proceed and cause NullPointer or some error? That way at least the JVM problem can be brought to light.

Answer (score 2):

I would also prefer the <0 approach. The reason why == -1 approach is widely used is because of the fact that the functions would indeed return -1 if the index is missing and the case of "extended function" will never happen, according to Java documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases advisable to stick to the Java doc as closely as possibly.
See Java Doc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29

... according to it: -1 will be returned.

So I would always check for -1.  If you have a specific value to check, its safer to check for that specific value, to protect against future code changes in java api.

For example, if you get a -2, that means that somethings is seriously wrong in your JVM. It doesn't mean "not found". It would be better for code to proceed to and cause an Exception/Error.

Answer (score 0):

According to javadoc indexOf is always supposed to return -1 if character does not occur in sequence
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29

Answer (score 0):

As Sandeep Nair points out the javaDoc explains it, but I want to comment a bit.

Both would work fine and I wouldn't say one is "better" than the other. The reason many people write `== -1` is that there is a general convention that search methods return -1 if "stuff cannot be found". We cannot use 0 since they are used as indices in arrays etc.

So, it's a matter of opinion. As long as the convention stays, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `-1` simply because I want to check what I'm expecting.

I'm not expecting `-2`. If I got `-2`, that'd probably mean I have some issues. Checking what you're expecting is just better than checking what you *may* expect.