# Performance when comparing the results of indexOf

Tags: javascript, performance, comparison

As you probably already know, the returned values of `indexOf` are either the `index` (found) or `-1` (not found).

There are many ways to test this result, some of them are:

```
if (result != -1) //different than -1
if (result >= 0) //greater or equal to 0
```

And other not so common options:

```
if (result + 1) //-1 turns to: -1 + 1 = 0 (falsish value)
if (~result) //-1 turns to: -(-1 + 1) = 0 (falsish value)
```

And countless of other options...

Which method performs good across all browsers?

Comment: related (about best practices) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175818/best-practice-for-testing-return-value-of-indexof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran some [intensive tests](http://jsperf.com/not-vs-gt-vs-ge/4) a while ago, I compared all these combinations:

```
if (~results) 
if (results > -1) 
if (!(results < 0))
if (results >= 0)
if (!(results <= -1))
if (results != -1)
if (!(results == -1))
if (results + 1)
if (!(results + 1))
```

On [my tests](http://jsperf.com/not-vs-gt-vs-ge/4), I added two lines each time, one with a successful result and one that failed. The reason for this is because we want the average of both scenarios to have a better picture of how it will usually perform.

What I concluded is that `~x` and `x >= 0` are really good options, but I will go for the later one because readability and easier code-maintainability.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance you might consider making your own indexOf method. Check out this  [performance test](http://jsperf.com/testcase-for-finding-index-of-value-in-array/2), where the result surprised me a little. Also note that IE8 and below doesn't support indexOf